# Logging in to FTP and getting result

Tags: c#, ftp

How would I attempt to log in to ftp and get the result with c#?
So for example, if the Login Credentials were incorrect, it would inform me that the Login Credentials are incorrect, and if the connection to the server does not work, it will inform me that the connection to the server is not working.

My current code is

```
        try {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(@"ftp://.....");
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(".....", ".....");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

however I want to know if the login credentials are correct or incorrect. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my reading of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) for FtpWebRequest, it looks like you have to issue a command like `DownloadFile`, and the call `GetResponse` to invoke the session, and get any errors back from the server.